# setup google analytics magento

Tags: magento, google-analytics, installation

Hi i have added a Google analytic **account** number in the admin,do i also need to add the Google tracking code in the files to track,in Google it still showing the

> The Google Analytic tracking code has not been detected on your
>   website's home page

please tell me how can i setup the Google analytic to my site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxxxx']);//fake
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'fake.com']);//fake
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

do i need to add this type of code in files

Comment: Did you view browser source and search for `var _gaq = _gaq`? Did you clear cache if any?

Answer (score 5):

Once the account has been set up in the admin the JS code should be outputted automatically. Possible reasons why it still is not are:

1. Output is disabled for the "Google Analytics" module. Check under "Configuration"=>"Advanced" if that is the case.
2. Some layout update removes the block "google_analytics". Search your XML layout updates for lines containing "google_analytics" - there may be a "remove" node with this name.
3. The template file "googleanalytics/ga.phtml" is unreadable or missing
4. The setting "Cookie Restriction Mode" set to "yes" under "Web" will also prevent the code output

Answer (score 1):

If you have Firefox installed on your machine then install the Plugin for Firebug called "Omnibug", you can [find it on the developer's site.](http://www.rosssimpson.com/dev/omnibug.html)

When you open that tab when browsing your site you will see a number of requests being made to Google. If there are no requests showing up then Magento is not configured correctly to output the GATC (Google Analytics Tracking Code).

Also, check out the [Magento docs for setting up GATC](http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/setting-up-google-analytics/)

Answer (score 0):

Many times, GA takes up to 24 hours to show the data and update the tracking code status. Can you wait for some time and see if the hits start appearing?

A quick way to check this can be to try the realtime report and see if it is showing any data.

Answer (score 0):

I spent multiple days trying to figure this problem out, and tried lots of different solutions. Apparently there are a lot of things that can keep Google Analytics from working on Magento. Oleg's advice was very good and fairly comprehensive and covers most of the answers I found. It did miss one of the explanations, though.

Apparently, between version 1.3 and 1.4 Magento switched how it handled Google Analytics. If you had a copy of any of any of the below in your custom template:

```
1column.phtml
2columns-left.phtml
2columns-right.phtml
3columns.phtml
```

Then you need to add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>`right above `<div class="wrapper">` in any of above listed files that exist in your customized template. The location of the files will be in a directory like this: app/design/frontend/CustomGroup/Custom/template/page/

Additionally, you may need to add two entries to your page.xml file in the app/design/frontend/CustomGroup/Custom/layout folder:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
     <label>Page Top</label>
</block>

<block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />
```

The two entries should be placed right above the "header" block.

The credit for this solution goes to those who replied in this thread and to two posters on the Magento forum. If you look at the posts by Ross and ceefour, you will see the solution that I have copied here described. Here is a link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/23325/P45/#t240114

Also, I wanted to note that you can potentially find out whether Google Analytics is in use if you search for the word "GoogleAnalytics" in your page source. In my case, it wasn't present until I followed the above steps. As stated above, Omnibug also works well and may be a more certain test.